# Looking for phone number containing a minus, like "123-456789"

Tags: sql, regex, database, postgresql

I have the following problem.

```
SELECT ....
FROM  .... 
WHERE "Phonenumber" LIKE '123456789'
  AND "*****" IS NOT NULL
```

So my situation is that I read these numbers out of a text file. These numbers are written like "123456789" but in my Postgres database the pattern is like "1234-56789".

The above statement doesn't produce any errors but no dataset either. So I was wondering how to write a statement that ignores "-" between the numbers.

I tried regular expressions but I couldn't find a solutions that fits my needs.

Comment: Is the minus always at the same position?

Comment: No. Im reading data out of the textfile where the phonenumbers are without any dashes. These numbers are also avaiable in the database but with dashes. So how do i look for this dataset with the number i read out of this textfile

Answer (score 2):

You could just use the [REPLACE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-string.html) function to strip out the dashes:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE REPLACE("Phonenumber", '-', '') LIKE '123456789'
AND ...
```

Alternatively process the strings from your text file and insert the dash between the fourth and fifth numbers, then use those for your SQL query.

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with PostgreSQL syntax, so the above query may not be exactly correct (I took my cue from the SQL in the question).

Answer (score 0):

To get those rows where the dash is after the fourth digit and is followed by five digits:

```
where "Phonenumber" ~ '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{5}'
```

To get those rows where the `-` is anywhere in the middle:

```
where "Phonenumber" ~ '[0-9]+-[0-9]+'
```

(so at least one digit, then the dash, then at least one more digit)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But my problem is i have to look for one person with this exact number i read out of the text file. Textfile-->Number without dashes Database-->Number with a Dash. I need a way to look for this particular dataset with the number i loaded out of the text file

Answer (score 0):

To replace one or more *single characters*, [**`translate()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) is generally faster (and shorter for multiple replacements) than `replace()` (which can replace whole strings).

```
...
WHERE translate("Phonenumber", '-', '') = '123456789'
```

It is also pointless to use [`LIKE` without wildcards](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE). Replace with a simple `=`.

> If *`pattern`* does not contain percent signs or underscores, then the
>   pattern only represents the string itself; in that case `LIKE` acts like
>   the equals operator.

To make this fast with bigger tables, create a matching [**functional index**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-expressional.html):

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_phone_idx ON tbl (translate("Phonenumber", '-', '')
```

Test performance with [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html).